# SO(3) gauge bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with a minimal instanton number

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

It is known that the SO(3) gauge bundle on the 4-manifold $M=\mathbb{CP}^2$, we can have the minimal instanton number 1.

Here we denote $SO(3)$ connection $A$ on a bundle $E$ over a $4$-manifold $M$,   let $F(A)$ denote its curvature $2$-form.

$$p_1(A)=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M\text{Tr}(F(A)\wedge F(A)).$$

> Question, do we know the explicit global structure of gauge bundle of $SO(3)$ on this $M=\mathbb{CP}^2$ given the minimal instanton number 1? Say
>   $$
> A_\mu=? 
> $$
>   for $\mu$ parametrizes the 4-coordinates of $M=\mathbb{CP}^2$? In principle, we should have the $SO(3)$ gauge flux through the 2-submanifold $\mathbb{CP}^1$ with
>   $$
> \int_{\mathbb{CP}^1} F(A)/(2\pi)= 1.
> $$
>   But how about the full functions of $A_\mu$ on $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214440256

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "explicit global structure of gauge bundle of $SO(3)$"?

Comment: I mean the $A_\mu$ connection function on the full $\mathbb{CP}^2$.